# Python Selenium keyboard actions move too fast

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to read price data by going through the candlesticks on a price chart. 
Here's part of my codes -

```py
close_prices = []
    While True:
        close_p = driver.find_element_by_xpath(close_path).text
        close_prices.append(close_p)
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT).perform()
```

My idea here is when I finished parsing for one candlestick, I could press LEFT to go to the next day's stick. However, I found by using Keys.ARROW_LEFT, it just moves too fast (or, the moving range is large) that it skipped several days in between. The chart is working fine when I manually press a LEFT on my keyboard. (i.e. moves 1-day by each press) In Selenium, it just doesn't work like what I do. (it moves several days)

I try to ask if there's any way to control the 'movements' of keyboard keys. i.e. to make it moves 'less'

Comment: Is the while loop part of a bigger structure? Reason for asking is from the way it is now, close_p always gets the first match i.e. the same value.

Comment: @0buz Thank you for the comment. No, it's not part of a bigger structure. It won't get the same value because each time when it press LEFT, it will move to another candlesticks, where a different price would appear in 'close_path'. So I catch new values

Comment: Ok, just wanted to check that before posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

use implict_wait()before every action  which is present in driver,you can also do using webdriverwait

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `close_p` as:

```
close_p = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, close_path))).text
```

WebDriverWait requires these imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried, but it didn't solve the problem. The LEFT still too 'large'. For example, when I press LEFT on my own, it only moves one candlestick. But if clicking by Selenium, it will move several (five, or even more) sticks.